# Date difference using Periods is giving incorrect result

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I am using the below data weave for finding the difference in number of days but it is giving output as '4' but it ideally should give result as '23'. Please let me know what must be corrected in the below dataweave.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import dw::core::Periods
---
Periods::between("19-12-2022" as Date {format: "dd-MM-yyyy"},"15-11-2022" as Date {format: "dd-MM-yyyy"}).days
```

Comment: Where did you get the 23 result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are looking only at the number of days but the function returns a period. If you remove `.days` at the end you will see it is actually returning `|P1M4D|` which is a period for 1 month and 4 days.

Instead you probably should use the [daysBetween() function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-daysbetween):

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
daysBetween("15-11-2022" as Date {format: "dd-MM-yyyy"}, "19-12-2022" as Date {format: "dd-MM-yyyy"})
```

That returns `34` by the way which seems about right.